# Displaying ModelAdmin fields in the same line issue

Tags: django, django-admin, conda

I delved in Django Documentation(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/) and I found out I can display fields name in the same line by wrapping with tuple. So this is how I did:

```
class MovieAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = (('title','length'),'release_year')

admin.site.register(Movie, MovieAdmin)
```

But my admin site shows only removed horizontal line between fields names, not displaying two names in the same line. Here's my screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7a0Pa.png)

Using Django 3.0.3, Python 3.8.

Thanks.

UPDATED

I forgot to mention I'm using conda environment. I cloned it and rerun it on the cloned environment, which took no effect at all.

Here's my `models.py`

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    length = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    release_year = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And I manipulated my code a bit to make it work, with no success though. Here's my `admin.py`.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Movie, Customer

class MovieAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fields = [('title','length'), 'release_year']

    search_fields = ['title']

    list_filter = ('release_year','length')

    list_display = ('title','release_year','length')

    list_editable = ['length']

admin.site.register(Movie, MovieAdmin)
```

I know this issue is not a huge headache, still I hope I can clarify stuffs. Thanks.

Comment: I tried and it worked. Please provide more details in question

Comment: Hi. I'm back to this issue and facing the same issue even if I run again with a new environment. By the way I'm using conda environment.

Comment: Can you share screenshot of your issue?

Comment: @sumitroy sorry for confusion. It was resizing browser that I didn't try to see if it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's embarrassing to admit I never tried resizing my browser. After making it bigger, it looks perfectly fine. Sorry for causing confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I have just installed Django and made the same model as yours, It is showing as you wanted

[image]

I think you have to check and install python and Django version again, Here is my requirements dependency 
Django==3.0.5
Python==3.8